# check if the time lies between two other times in 12 hr time span

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

The below code what i am trying is working if the time what i am checking is before the first time i am comparing with.

if timeToCompare  is after 6 PM its wroking good and if it lies between two time slots its working good but only if it 01:00:00 AM which is not in the time frame but still its going into if condition.

Please correct em where if going wrong.

```
    String string1 = "07:00:00 AM";
    Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a").parse(string1);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(time1);


    String string2 = "06:00:00 PM";
    Date time2;
    time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a").parse(string2);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(time2);
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    String timeToCompare = "01:00:00 AM";
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a").parse(timeToCompare);
    Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar3.setTime(d);
    calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

My timeToCompare  but be in between string1 and string2

```
    Date x = calendar3.getTime();
    if (x.after(calendar1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
        //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.
        System.out.println("Hi from time between given slots");
    }
```

1:00:00 AM is not in middle of those tow time's but still it is gogin into if condition and it is pritning "Hi from time between given slots"

Comment: Are you able to use Joda Time or Java 8's java.time package? That will make your life *much* easier. It would also help if you'd provide us a short but *complete* example, with sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Theses are the  import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

Comment: There's more to producing a short but complete example than adding imports. We should be able to copy your code, paste it into an empty text file, save it, and run it. Now, you're using Java 6 - which is horribly old, and you should really try to update to Java 8 - but you could still use Joda Time. Is there anything stopping you from doing so?

Comment: 1:00:00 AM *tomorrow* is definitely between 7:00:00 AM *today* and 6:00:00 PM *tomorrow*

Comment: You should also take note of the differences in [SimpleDateFormat pattern specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `H` (which you use) and `h`, `K`, and `k` — `H` is documented as _**Hour in day (0-23)**_ which lets you parse `22:33:44` but you also use `a` which would allow `22:33:44 AM` ... and that makes no sense.  If you are requiring AM/PM you should use `h` or `K`, **not** `H`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a day to string 2 and string 3. Internally, Java is storing your times as the following:

```
> calendar1.getTime()
Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 CST 1970
> calendar2.getTime()
Fri Jan 02 06:00:00 CST 1970
> calendar3.getTime()
Fri Jan 02 01:00:00 CST 1970
```

So, your time range is bigger than you think it is!

Comment: Is there any other way to find the solution

Comment: I am not quite sure what solution you are looking for. If you don't want your 1:00:00 AM to evaluate as in the interval, remove the `calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)` and `calendar3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)` lines.

Comment: @tom your problem is that your beginning and ending points are further apart than you think.  Your question title asks for how to find if a time is in a 12 hour span, and then you create a 35 hour span.

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect Parsing Pattern

You should be using lowercase `hh` for an hour value 1-12. The uppercase `HH` is for 24-hour clock 0-23.

## java.time

You should be using the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome.

The new framework includes a class for time-only values, [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). This class has no date, and no time zone. Yet note how a time zone is required to determine the current time.

```
String string1 = "07:00:00 AM";
String string2 = "06:00:00 PM";
String string3 = "01:00:00 AM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.ENGLISH );

LocalTime localTime1 = formatter.parse ( string1 , LocalTime :: from );
LocalTime localTime2 = formatter.parse ( string2 , LocalTime :: from );
LocalTime localTime3 = formatter.parse ( string3 , LocalTime :: from );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

These LocalTime objects have convenient `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods.

```
Boolean isFirstInputEarlierThanNow = localTime1.isBefore ( now );
```

The `LocalTime` class also implements the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. So you can sort them as seen in this example code.

```
List<LocalTime> localTimes = Arrays.asList ( localTime1 , localTime2 , localTime3 , now );
Collections.sort ( localTimes );

LocalTime earliest = localTimes.get ( 0 ); // Index, meaning zero-based counting.
LocalTime latest = localTimes.get ( localTimes.size () - 1 ); // Index (zero-based counting), so subtract one.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localTimes: " + localTimes );
System.out.println ( "isFirstInputEarlierThanNow: " + isFirstInputEarlierThanNow );
System.out.println ( "earliest: " + earliest + " … latest: " + latest );
```

When run.

> localTimes: [01:00, 07:00, 18:00, 19:26:41.932]
>
> isFirstInputEarlierThanNow: true
>
> earliest: 01:00 … latest: 19:26:41.932